# Underscore template <script type="text/template></script> and nested quotes

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

I'm working on a Laravel/Blade project and I'm using underscore to render content on the page. As a very simple example, in my blade file I have:

```
<div class="test-template">

</div>

<script class="template-container" type="text/template">
    <div class="sample-class">
        <h1><%= title %></h1>
    </div>
</script>
```

My javascript to render the template looks like this:

```
var template = _.template( $( ".template-container" ).html() );
var markup = template({
  title: 'Title'
});
$('.test-template').html(markup);
```

The issue I'm having is that when the template is rendered every attribute that has quotes around it (in my blade file) gets wrapped in two sets of quotes.

[image]

Does anyone know how to prevent this double wrapping? I realized that if I remove the quotes from the class name in my blade file it technically renders the quotes properly. The problem there is that I can't use more than one class name per element.

Comment: Those are two different sets of quotes. It looks as if you pasted code into a word processor, thereby replacing the plain quotes with ortographic ones. Never use a word processor for code, always use a plain text editor.